# How to create session table in rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

We want to create session table in our rails (3.2.9) engine. But `rake db:sessions:create` does not work in rails engine root directory (only works under the dummy directory). Is there way to create sessions in rails engine? Or can we add rake db:sessions:create in Rakefile for the engine so we can use the rake command?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an engine is not a rails app, it's not linked with a database and you cannot create the session table, only add a migration for that.

Couldn't you just copy the migration from dummy to the migrations folder of your engine ?

Comment: An engine could have its own models or tables. According to rails engine guide(http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), it is almost the same as a rails app. Can you elaborate "not linked with a database..."?

Comment: I mean an engine does not have a `config/database.yml` file, you cannot run `rails s` in the root of the engine. It is only linked with a database when it is used in an application, like in the `test/dummy` folder.

Comment: I see. Is the files/app under dummy solely for testing purpose and never be called for execution?

Comment: The dummy app is used for test yes but I'm also use to run `rails s` in it when I develop my engine.